# Normalize random value of _int64

Tags: c, visual-c++, math

Let's suppose we have noramlly distributed random int values from function:

```
unsigned int myrand();
```

The commonest way to shrink its range to [0, A] (int A) is to do as follows:

```
(double)rand() / UINT_MAX * A
```

Now I need to do the same for values in range of __int64:

```
unsigned __int64 max64;
unsigned __int64 r64 = myrand();
r64 <<= 32;
r64 |= myrand();
r64 = normalize(r64, max64);
```

The problem is to normalize return range by some __int64 because it could not be placed in double. I wouldn't like to use various libraries for big numbers due to performance reasons. Is there a way to shrink return range quickly and easily while saving normal distribution of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you give

```
(double)myrand() / UINT_MAX * A
```

is already broken. For example, if A = 1 and you want integers in the range [0, 1] you will only ever get a value of 1 if myrand () returned UINT_MAX. If you meant the range [0, A), that is only the value 0, then it is still broken because it will in that case return a value outside the range. No matter what, you are introducing a bias.

If you want A+1 different values from 0 to A inclusive, and 2^32 ≤ A < 2^64, you proceed as follows:

Step 1: Calculate a 64 bit random number R as you did. If A is one less than a power of two, you return R shifted by the right amount.

Step 2: Find how many different random values would be mapped to the same output value. Mathematically, that number is floor (2^64 / (A + 1)). 2^64 is too large, but that is no problem because it is equal to 1 + floor ((2^64 - (A + 1)) / (A + 1)), calculated in C or C++ as D = 1 + (- (A + 1)) / (A + 1) if A has type uint64_t.

Step 3: Find how many different random values should be mapped by calculating N = D * (A + 1). If R >= N then go back to Step 1.

Step 4: Return R / D.

No floating point arithmetic needed. The result is totally unbiased. If A < 2^32 you fall back to the 32 bit version (or you use the 64 bit version as well, but it calls myrandom () twice as often as needed).

Of course you calculate D and N only once unless A changes.

Comment: Seems to be true :) The drawback is that we need to generate random number several times in some cases, especially when A gets larger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "long double" if it is available in your platform.

Comment: how does that `shrink return range`?